# How to delete elements in an array an reduce its size?

Tags: java, arrays, reduce, shift

I have an array of byte that I want to process. My goal is to remove fixed size patterns.

I am using the following code :

```
byte buffer[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int position; // position of the patern in the stream
int length = buffer.length(); 
int pattern_size = 64; // size of the patern to delete

for(i = position; i<length; i++){
    // Shift the bytes 
    buffer[i] = buffer[i+pattern_size];
}

for(i = length; i>=(length-pattern_size); i--){
    // Adding 0s at the end to make up for the loss of data
    buffer[i]=0;
}

data_removed = data_removed + pattern_size;
```

As you can see I am adding zeros at the end of the byte array. I would actually prefer to reduce the size of the array. How can I do this ?

Comment: Your title should be `in an array`, since a `List` is somewhat an dynamic array. In order to do it with lists you´d need to create an array with the size `originalArray-1`. Afterwards you could use `System.arrayCopy` to copy all the values from the one array to the other.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my title. Indeed creating a new array is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry that this probably isn't going to be what you want to hear, but in java, arrays are technically fixed and size cannot be directly changed.

There are ways around it, and the method (not a java method!) that I suggest would be to use a linked list data structure. It sounds intimidating, but there's tons of help on YouTube when it comes to java.

In a nutshell, it's a way of letting you connect "item types" together in whatever order that you want. One item is either in front of an item or behind another item, so it's similar to an array in this sense.

Using a linked list would also allow you to add zeros to the end of your data as well as giving you the freedom of being able to manipulate the content in your data without the concern of size.

I really hope this helped, I'm sorry if it wasn't much. Teaching data structures in a single comment wouldn't be an easy feat, haha!

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will check linked data structures out then, they seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Try this link out! Fairly straight forward: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=195KUinjBpU

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for indeed !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reduce the size of array besides creating new array since its size is final. Try any of [java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementations for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that with an [Arraylist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)